# Show Image in Callout Label

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer of point data that includes fields for an ID number and an image file path. I would like to display the ID number for each point by default and be able to display the image in a callout for some points only.

To help illustrate the goal I have set up map tips that display the image using HTML. In the screen capture below the result is visible for point 17, but this only displays on the computer screen when a user hovers the mouse cursor over a point for a few seconds.

The label for point 21 on the other hand is displayed using a callout. I would like this callout for point 21 to do display similar to the map tip for point 17 so that I can display the image for specific points and have them visible on the final printed map. Is this possible to achieve?

[image]

For reference the HTML for the map tip is as follows:

```html
<h3>[% BotanicName %]</h3>
<p>[% right("Photo1",12) %]</p>
<img src="file:///[% Photo1 %]" width="250" />
```